# More than 2 millions rectangles in a WPF canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a custom control for semiconductor wafermap [image]

Each of those small rectangle need to satisfy following requirements;
1) Tooltip to show the index
2) clickable to include or exclude from the wafermap definition.

no of dies in the wafermap may cross 2 millions in the case of 1400 x 1450 dies.

at certain point i need to show all the dies in a window (most of the clicking will happen in zoomed view).

Currently I am adding each die separately using Rectangle shape and store the coordinate information (index like (10,10)) for the tooltip as an attached property.

I use different style to each die; depending on certain calculation and position of the die.

```
DieStyle1 = new Style { TargetType = typeof(Rectangle) };
DieStyle1.Setters.Add(new Setter(Shape.FillProperty, Brushes.MediumSlateBlue));
DieStyle1.Setters.Add(new Setter(Shape.StrokeProperty, Brushes.White));
DieStyle1.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(DieStyle1_MouseDown)));
```

this approach is slow and use high memory too. so suggest a better way to achieve this in WPF?

Comment: Questions that ask for "the best way" are usually closed here. It's usually expected that you post some sort of effort to do things yourself (even if it's not "the best way"), and then ask specific questions about that code. Can you [edit] your question and add the code you've written that isn't working as well as you'd like? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you could use a bitmap and use simple coordinate transformation to determine what to show in the tool-tip or how to respond to mouse events.  Have you considered using a bitmap to show and manipulate your wafermaps?

Comment: Do *not* use separate/composite objects. Use a control that knows how to draw the cells/lines itself. You'll have to handle translating the events manually, but it should be quite trivial to perform the mapping.

Comment: You don't necessarily need 2 million event handlers and 2 milion tooltips. Each area is defined with its coordinates, state, text. So you can use a small database or xml-list to look-up for the information you want to show.

Comment: Try draw all your rectangles in one WriteableBitmap and use MouseMove, MouseLeftButtonDown events and mouse coordinate in them.

Answer (score 1):

In creating a designer for christmas tree lights, I ran into the same problem.  Using UIElement or Shapes is way too slow when you get to 100+ items.  The best approach to handle a very large number of items entails using double-buffering with your own managed buffer of the image and a structure to handle the clicks.  I have posted my project which should give you a good start.  It can be obtained at:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlightsdesigner/

You are interested in the Controls\ChannelitemsCanvas.cs.  It can be modified to suit your needs and uses a quad-tree to store the rectangles so that click events can be quickly determined.