# Custom Wafer map control using C# .NET

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, bitmap, wpf-controls

I am an experienced LabVIEW programmer but a newbie at C#. I am using C# on Visual Studio 2010. I am making a program to automate a wafer prober. I need to make a wafer map control that shows the current probe position, a different color for probed/unprobed die, etc. A wafer map is a 2-d grid of rectangles, where the height and width of rectangles is programmable at runtime. The color of each rectangle shows the status of that die on the wafer: probing in progress, untested, passed, failed, etc. So for each X,Y location, there is a color that can indicate the die status. So far the only way I have seen to do this is to make a custom bitmap and display this in the GUI. Is this the only way to make a wafer map? I am still coming up the learning curve on Windows Forms. Is there some shortcut I am missing using Forms or WPF?

Comment: If don't already know winforms, don't even waste your time learning it. It is a really old technology that is not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications.

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with using a bitmap.  It is not the only way, in Winforms you could just draw the grid with the Paint event and call Invalidate(Rectangle) method to get it updated.  WPF likes you using the Rectangle class.  This is not a very complicated task, the wise thing to do is to just get started on it with the help of an introductory book on whatever class library you like.  So you'll at least have a targeted question to ask about it.

Comment: All newer .Net UI technologies (WPF, WinRT XAML, Silverlight, Windows Phone) are all XAML-based and share a common mentality (MVVM). This means that if you learn WPF, for example, you can port your knowledge and code to other frameworks such as WinRT XAML or Silverlight. Whereas if you learn winforms you're stuck with winforms and its limitations forever.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on how to create diagrams with different elements, shapes, positions, sizes, etc on WPF. See my examples [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/643085) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15469477/643085) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16947081/643085). All of these are fully  MVVM (which means that Data and Application logic are not tightly coupled to presentation). These examples show things that are really easy to implement in WPF but would take a huge effort in older technologies such as winforms.

Comment: Either use WPF or GDI+ in Winforms. Certainly would not recommend using a DataGridView(!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202730/datagridview-to-draw-wafer-map

Comment: This might also help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650995/more-than-2-millions-rectangles-in-a-wpf-canvas